# How to understand the solution of Brezis' Exercise 3.13 part 4 (odd multiples of unit vectors converges weakly to 0)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-explanation

Here is the exercise that I am working on:

> Let $E$ be a space Banach, $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset E$, $x \in E$ and \begin{equation*}
>    K_{n}= \overline{con(\bigcup_{i=n}^{\infty}\{xi\})}.
>   \end{equation*}
> 4. In $\ell^p$, $1 < p < \infty$, construct a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $\bigcap_{n = 1} ^\infty K_n = \{ x \}$, and $(x_n)$ is not bounded.

The solution in the book gave the following example:

> Consider the sequence $x_n = (0, 0, \ldots, \underset{(n)}{n}, 0, \ldots)$ when $n$ is odd, and $x_n = 0$ when $n$ is even.

In the previous parts I have shown that if $x_n$ converges to $x$ weakly, then $\bigcap_{n = 1} ^\infty K_n = \{ x \}$. It is clear that $x_n$ is not bounded as we can always pick a big enough odd number. It is not clear to me how $x_n$ in the given example would converge weakly to $0$.

Comment: What is $con(\cdot)$ here?

Comment: @BrianTung It is the convex hall of the given set.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $(x^{1},x^{2},...) \in K_n$ then $x^{i}=0$ for all $i <n$. So if $(x^{1},x^{2},...) \in \bigcap K_n$ then $x^{i}=0$ for each $i$.

Comment: I don't think I understood the hint. I do believe that $\bigcap_{n = 1} ^\infty K_n = \{ 0 \}$ in this example, but I am not seeing how the hint would imply weak convergence of $x_n$ to $0$?

Comment: @PartialT I am not using your argument. There is no need for proving weak convergence or use any previous result. I am proving directly that $\cap K_n =\{0\}$.